# Using Selenium on WordPress Quizzes

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I was working on a page tester with Selenium Webdriver for Python and ran into a particular problem. At one point I have what is basically a multiple choice quiz, on which I want to try to do random answers over and over until I finish the quiz on its own. I have no limitation on how many times the code can try to do the quiz, or any sort of captcha.

The problem arises on the fact that this quiz changes dynamically. The quiz plugin can be found here (if you'd like to see some of the quiz's code)

https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-pro-quiz/

This is the code I have tried to use:

```
wait =WebDriverWait(driver, wait)
element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, 'wpProQuiz_questionInput')))
answers = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//input[@class='wpProQuiz_questionInput'][1]")
mouse.move_to_element(answers[1]).click().perform()
```

and it works well, but only for the first question. Then I proceed to click on the "next" button

```
next_btn = driver.find_element_by_name("next")
next_btn.click()
```

which also works, but when the loop starts again, and tries to find wpProQuiz_questionInput again, it gives me a time out exception because it  doesn't find the item.

I'm not sure if I have to somehow tell selenium that the quiz has been updated, or to somehow listen for it. Restarting the page causes the quiz to restart as well.

Thank you, let me know if there's more information I can give to help you help me!

UPDATE:

After the comment showing me that all questions are on list form.

Very useful info, thank you. However I still run into some trouble.

```
        wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

        print "Waiting for quiz to be visible"
        element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, 'wpProQuiz_list')))
        questions = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//ol[@class='wpProQuiz_list'][1]")
        print questions
        print "printed questions"
        for question in questions:
            try:
                print "trying to find answers"
                answers = question.find_elements_by_tag_name("input")
                print "Answers:"
                print answers
                answers[1].click()
            except Exception as e:
                print "Error: ", e

          try:
                next_btn = driver.find_element_by_name("next")
                next_btn.click()
                sleep(10)

            except:
                end_btn = driver.find_element_by_name("endQuizSummary")
                end_btn.click()
            sleep(10)
```

I make the program wait for long enough until the elements are visible, but it seems that Selenium doesn't realize that the elements that were hidden, are now visible.

Comment: They list a demo [here](http://www.it-gecko.de/wp-pro-quiz-quiz-plugin-fuer-wordpress.html). Looks like a quiz is a series of `li.wpProQuiz_listItem` elements. They're rendered in advance and then use show/hide to display the individual questions. `wpProQuiz_questionInput` is a class for a particular type of answer (in this case, a fill-in-the-textbox answer). `element_to_be_clickable()` gets you clickable items; hidden items aren't considered clickable. Also, the next question may not be the right class (e.g.: `.wpProQuiz_questionList` is the answer set for a multichoice question).

Comment: Thank you Ouruborus. I have updated the question with my new try, I now get a ElementNotVisibleException.

Comment: Could I possibly change the css from selenium to make it visible myself?

Comment: I think I answered my own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what my solution needed was a different point of view (Thanks ouroborus) and some Javascript

```
        wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

        print "Waiting for quiz to be visible"
        element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, 'wpProQuiz_list')))
        quiz = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//ol[@class='wpProQuiz_list']")
        questions = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("wpProQuiz_listItem")
        print questions
        print "printed questions"
        print len(questions)
        for question in questions:
            while True:
                try:
                    print "trying to find answers"
                    answers = question.find_elements_by_tag_name("input")
                    print "Answers:"
                    print answers
                    el = answers[1]
                    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].style.visibility = 'visible';", el)
                    el.click()
                    break

                except Exception as e:
                    print "Error: ", e
                    sleep(1)


            while True:
                try:
                    next_btn = driver.find_elements_by_name("next")[questions.index(question)]
                    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].style.visibility = 'visible';", next_btn)
                    next_btn.click()
                    sleep(5)
                    break
                except Exception as e:
                    print e
                    sleep(5)
```

Lack of efficiency aside, I just wanted to make it work, the solution I found was to use Javascript to make my element visible and therefore be able to click it without problems. Now I can replace those 1s with random integers and I have a program that does the quiz randomly.